# I know how to check that the dot product is a scalar. But how do I check that that a function like temperature is a scalar?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I want temperature to be the same at the same point in $(x,y)$ and polar $(r,\theta)$. But how is that enforced that mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a function that calculates the temperature at a point $(x, y)$, you can also calculate the temperature at the point in polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ by using the conversion $(r\cos \theta, r\sin\theta)$. Then you can check what the temperature is at $(r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)$ and see if it is the same as the temperature at point $(x,y)$. If it isn't, you can set the temperature at the point $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ to be the temperature at $(x, y)$. Or you can try to find a new point $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ that has the same temperature as at $(x, y)$, depending on what you mean.